# Custom namespace components not displayed in Spring Integration Graph.

Tags: spring, graph, integration

The xsd references are specified in the context xml files, but the components do not appear in the integration-graph, nor for selection. Is there any other way to install the xsd

Comment: Are you talking about in sts visual diagram?

Comment: If you have the spring integration dependency, go to the namespace tab of your context file view. You should see the integration namespace available with the `int` check box. Check it. See if that works.

Comment: Yes, Integration graph tab in STS, the xsd namespace is available with a checkbox in the namespace tab, but the custom namespaces are not available for selection(nor are they getting displayed in the graphical flow) in the integration-graph tab

Comment: Not really sure what you mean _"the custom namespaces are not available for selection"_ Does that mean you can't select the check box for `int`? Also, so you can't click on one of the components (like "channel") and then click on the graph and place the channel? Does that work?

Comment: Say I have a custom namespace declaration like xmlns:custtransformer for which I have an xsd. This namespace is available for selection under the namespaces column(I can select the namespace and on the right side the associated xsd), but the custom namespace component is not available as a draggable component on the Integration-graph palette(the palettes that shows the Channels, Routing, Transformation...) I am expecting a new group for my namespace which is not there.